# Web scraping in dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a general question about scraping from dynamic content, I am trying to parse Reddit pages with selenium, new content is loaded as I scroll down, is the best way to do it, is to save the HTML after each scroll parse then scroll back again?

What I am trying to do is get all links of images on someone page.

Also, one more question, if i scroll all the way down to the bottom, will the HTML (from selenium) at that time contain the entire page i.e has the entire image links?

Comment: Have you checked if it does?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape Reddit, the easiest path is probably:

1. Create an API account on Reddit [https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/]
2. Search via the API, instead of scrolling through selenium. Use a library like Praw [https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/] if you prefer, or access the API directly, as per the docs.

Comment: Thanks, but most of these images come from different sites (Imugr, Flickr...) so i don't think using API will give those links.

Comment: this is the right answer, but once you switch to the API, you are no longer "scraping"

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg it is true if I use API, I won't be actually scraping, my question was a two-part question for a general case, many sites load JSON when scroll (or do something), I posted Reddit as an example of a site that does this. My question was, in general, "is this way to do it on a dynamic site".
The second part of the question also was not answered as to if I scroll towards the bottom(loading all json along the way) will selenium  HTML give all content?